# How to enable ssl authentication for a new Kafka consumer in Flink?

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, flink-streaming

Flink enthusiasts,
I'm consuming from a kafka broker in a remote server that has ssl authentication enabled. How do I config my FlinkKafkaConsumer to comply with ssl authentication? Which flags/properties and values need to be set in the Properties objects for the Consumer? Any pointers to either documentation or sample code is welcome.

Disclosure: this is not Kerberos server ssl authentication.

Many thanks
Alex